# Google Chrome saved html files of some pages don't show properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, web

I don't remember if this ever worked but I've an issue with downloading some pages html files, that they don't show up properly on Google Chrome. However, if I open them up on another browser such as Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer itself, I can see the page without any problems.

I'm gonna make an example with https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Main_Page

Go on that page and you should see how it looks by default.

Now this is how it looks like after downloading the html of it (full html with folder) and open it after that with Google Chrome.

[image: Picture 1]

but it's not supposed to look like that at all, if I open it up on Internet Explorer.

[image: Picture 2]

As you see on Internet Explorer it looks fine same on Microsoft Edge, it could be that some small things don't show up but these are okay.

**Errors:**

```
[Deprecation] CSS cannot be loaded from `file:` URLs unless they end in a `.css` file extension.
Valve%20Developer%20Community.html:12 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/Valve%20Developer%20Community_files/load(1).php".
load.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: mw is not defined
    at load.php:1

(anonymous) @ load.php:1
Valve%20Developer%20Community.html:13 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/Valve%20Developer%20Community_files/screen.less".
load(2).php:17 GET file:///C:/w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=jquery%2Cmediawiki&only=scripts&skin=valve&version=20141001T014210Z net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

(anonymous) @ load(2).php:17
load(3).php:154 GET file:///C:/w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=jquery.client%2Ccookie%2CmwExtension%2Cthrottle-debounce%7Cmediawiki.legacy.ajax%2Cwikibits%7Cmediawiki.notify%2Ctoc%2Cutil%7Cmediawiki.page.startup%7Cskins.vector.js&skin=valve&version=20171215T202648Z&* net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
addScript @ load(3).php:154
doRequest @ load(3).php:158
work @ load(3).php:160
request @ load(3).php:157
load @ load(3).php:164

(anonymous) @ Valve Developer Community.html:34
Valve Developer Community.html:255 GET file:///C:/w/skins/common/images/wiki.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

load(3).php:154 GET file:///C:/w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=jquery.checkboxShiftClick%2Chidpi%2ChighlightText%2CmakeCollapsible%2Cmw-jump%2Cplaceholder%2Csuggestions%7Cmediawiki.action.view.postEdit%7Cmediawiki.api%2Ccldr%2Chidpi%2CjqueryMsg%2Clanguage%2CsearchSuggest%2Cuser%7Cmediawiki.language.data%2Cinit%7Cmediawiki.libs.pluralruleparser%7Cmediawiki.page.ready%7Cskins.vector.collapsibleNav&skin=valve&version=20171215T202648Z&* net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
addScript @ load(3).php:154
doRequest @ load(3).php:158
work @ load(3).php:160
request @ load(3).php:157
load @ load(3).php:164

(anonymous) @ Valve Developer Community.html:259
Valve Developer Community.html:1 Failed to load https://developer.valvesoftware.com/w/index.php?action=ajax: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not
```

But why does Google Chrome show it not properly? On Icognito mode it doesn't show it properly either, it's not because of a setting as it seem, you can try to reproduce it your own to see.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Check the browser's developer console for errors. I'd bet there's something about HTTPS assets on a non-HTTPS page or something similar in there.

Comment: added the errors that I found in the console

Answer (score 1):

This seems pretty clear, and would definitely explain the behavior shown in the screenshots:

> CSS cannot be loaded from `file:` URLs unless they end in a `.css` file extension.

Comment: it doesn't say which file and I have only one file ending with .css and I still don't know how Internet Explorer can make it.

Comment: IE and Chrome frequently have different URLs for things like this. Look in the source for any `<link>` tags referencing a non-`.css` CSS file.

Comment: So you mean like the Tab Source in the dev tools?